# Stream de áudio

Tags: android, streaming

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo que tem em uma das funções reproduzir um *streaming* de uma radio, o problema é que ele funcionou em 1 Moto G2, 1 Moto G3 e no meu ASUS Zenfone 2 LASER, ele simplesmente não funciona é como se ele não suportasse o protocolo.

- [Link 1 - Usado](http://104.247.207.42:8041/stream)
- [Link 2 - Funciona no Zen 2](http://rtsp://wz3.dnip.com.br/acarauhd/acarauhd.stream)

todos os aparelhos estão no Android 6.0.1

```
 String url = "http://104.247.207.42:8041/stream";
    mp = new MediaPlayer();
    mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    try {
        mp.setDataSource(url);
        mp.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Log.e(TAG, "SecurityException");
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Log.e(TAG, "IllegalStateException");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Log.e(TAG, "IOException");
    }
```

Código que prepara o player no `onCreate()`, ele toca no `onStart()` do serviço.
queria saber porque ele não toca, não retorna nem um erro, e se eu posso usar outra lib sem grandes dificuldades para substituir o MediaPlayer do **Android**.

Comment: Qual a versão do android nos aparelhos?

Comment: Pode ser um problema com Codec, já verificou isso?

Comment: a versão é 6.0.1 em todos, estou verificando o codec e vou testar com uma lib que é bem similar ao mediaplayer nativo do android.

Comment: Para quem teve o mesmo problema que o meu, [Aqui esta o link](https://github.com/wseemann/FFmpegMediaPlayer) da lib que eu usei, é a mesma coisa do MediaPlayer do android, e funcionou perfeitamente

Comment: Você pode responder a sua própria pergunta, se já conseguiu resolver, vai ajudar outros no futuro, e você poderá marca-la como resposta aceita em 2 dias @JuniorNascimento

Comment: certo, vou faze-lo.